# Firebase Dynamic Link Preview Content

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have a dynamic link which is linked / setup through my `Firebase` console.

[image]

This link works as expected through a Facebook link share generated from the following:

```
NSURL *link = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://myapp.page.link/page?parameter=123"];

NSString *dynamicLinksDomain = @"myapp.page.link";
FIRDynamicLinkComponents *linkBuilder = [[FIRDynamicLinkComponents alloc]
                                         initWithLink:link
                                         domain:dynamicLinksDomain];
linkBuilder.iOSParameters = [[FIRDynamicLinkIOSParameters alloc]
                             initWithBundleID:@"com.example.MyApp"];

content.contentURL = linkBuilder.url;

[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:controller withContent:content delegate:self];
```

---

The post displays the information as expected in the small cell:

[image]

---

### The problem:

- ❌ When the user taps the link **WITH** the passed `parameter=123`, it delivers them to the "correct" but very much empty page (shown below on the **LEFT**.)
- ✅ When the user taps the link **WITHOUT** the passed `parameter=123`, it delivers them to the intended page (shown below on the **RIGHT**).

[image]

---

As I said above, the links work fine. Meaning, when tapping "OPEN" it takes the user to either the app (if installed) or the App Store. Even **with** the parameter passed, I *do* receive it correctly in the app through the URL, but my question is:

> How can I pass parameters through my dynamic link while maintaining the preview page **with** my applications content?

---

Any help is much appreciated - thanks in advance!

### NOTE:

I have tried adding components to my dynamic link deep link through the Firebase console, such as `...page.link/parameterID` to see if it anticipates looking for a value there. No luck. I'm sure it's something to do with the setup but I've been unable thus far to **keep the content with the passed parameter.**

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might be confusing the deep link in your dynamic link with the subdomain for your actual Firebase Dynamic Link (.page.link URL). So rather than use 'https://myapp.page.link/page?parameter=123' as your deep link parameter, you'll want to use your own company domain name like https://example.com/page?parameter=123.

Since you're passing in a URL with your Firebase Dynamic Link subdomain, that is the deep link that your app is receiving, which is probably not what you intend.

Check out the docs here for more info:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/create

You'll notice that the deep link URL is https://example.com, whereas the subdomain example.page.link is used as the Dynamic Links domain instead.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Am I then able to pass any parameter value there? It needs to depend on a users info not just always a constant i.e. 123

Comment: The parameter must be dynamic also - the value will be set in-app depending on the content the user has shared. It will be different every time so it can't be statically set in Firebase's console

Comment: @WillVonUllrich Yes that is correct. You probably want to look at generating Dynamic Links programmatically via the builder APIs, and setting the parameter as needed on the deep link that your app will handle.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/create

Also note that you'll want to make sure you URL encode any parameters you pass in.

Answer (score 0):

Here, we are talking about the the meta-tag information that is displayed on the Preview page.

These are automatically taken from the URL you create the link for or you can set these up when creating the link. Add these parameters when you build the Dynamic link.

- Title (st)
- Description (sd)
- Image (si)

More info how they work is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/link-previews).

The problem seems to be, that your page https://example.com/page?parameter=123 does not have the meta-tag setup correctly.